# Wrap lstlisting in minipage and start on new line

Tags: listings, line-breaking, page-breaking, paragraphs

I don't want page-breaks inside my listings, so using `\lstnewenvironment` I wrap my listings inside a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{snippet}[1][]{%
  \lstset{#1}
  \noindent\minipage{\linewidth}
}
{\endminipage}
```

However, now there is no new line between the text and a `snippet`. For example,

```
This is some text.
\begin{snippet}
Some code snippet
\end{snippet}
```

... results in the following.

[image: snippet]

I tried adding the `\par` command inside the environment, i.e.,

```
\lstnewenvironment{snippet}[1][]{%
  \lstset{#1}
  \par\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}
}
{\endminipage}
```

but this resulted in an error: `Paragraph ended before \lstnewenvironment@ was complete.`

Is there a way to always start this minipage on a new line?

Comment: use `\endgraf` instead of `\par` and also after `\endminipage`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure why, but that seems to work perfectly. I ended up adding `\endgraf` at the end of the environment too. You can add an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low level `Paragraph ended before ....` error is generated by TeX if it sees the token `\par`: it neither checks that `\par` has its usual meaning at that point, nor checks for other commands that might have that meaning. LaTeX (and plain TeX) have an alias `\endgraf` that is defined to have the usual meaning of `\par` for use when `\par` is locally redefined or when you want to avoid this error.